# c++ declare vector in header file

Tags: c++, vector

In c++, I have a vector declared in the header file of a class. In the cpp file, when I try to access the vector or push new element to vector, it causes program terminated. How to solve this problem?

**MyClass.h**

```
MyClass{
    private:
       vector<Group*> myVector;

    public:
       MyClass();
       void someMethod(string group_name);
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(){

}

void MyClass::someMethod(string group_name){
    if(myVector.empty()){ // cause error
       cout << "empty" << endl;
    }

    Group g(group_name);
    myVector.push_back(&g); // also cause error
}
```

I called someMethod In the main program

```
 MyClass *myclass;
 myclass->someMethod("aaa");
```

Comment: Do you mind posting [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The lines that throw the errors look fine to me. However pushing the reference to a local variable to a vector is a bad idea (see Pete's answer)  But to get a real answer, you should at least post the exception thrown and the complete (but minimal!) code needed to reproduce the problem (i.e. how is someMethod called?)

Comment: My question is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing that should outright give you a segmentation fault in this code. Yes pushing a pointer to a variable that is about to be destructed is a really bad idea but you shouldn't be getting a seg fault when calling empty or push_back because of that. From what you've given us we can only speculate right now.

Comment: @NoName No, your question was not verifiable beause at least there is no `main()` function to call functions in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(myVector.empty()){ // cause error
```

No, this code is just fine. Something else is causing an error here.

```
Group g(group_name);
myVector.push_back(&g); // also cause error
```

This code, however, is a disaster waiting to happen. When `g` goes out of scope it gets destroyed, and the pointer stored in `myVector` points to random stuff. Any later use of that pointer can do strange things, including seeming to work just fine.

Comment: Even using vector<int> and add an element with push_back also didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create an instance of MyClass: `MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();` , so myClass just contains some garbage.

Answer (score -1):

```
MyClass *myclass;
 myclass->someMethod("aaa");
```

You are trying to dereference a pointer containing garbage value, the code should look like this :

```
MyClass *myclass;
```

//initialize a myclass instance

```
Myclass cMyclass
```

//assign it to your pointer to myClass :

```
myclass = &cMyclass
```

//then you can dereference it :

```
 myclass->someMethod("aaa");
```